# How to Emulate Double Dispatch in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, double-dispatch

I'm, trying to emulate a Double Dispatch in Objective-C.

I know Objective-C does not support function/method overloading. But can you emulate this?

Any idea.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882396/double-dispatch-for-collision-handling-with-spritekit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [repo](https://github.com/jghg02/DispatchiOSObjC) give an example of how to Implement `Double Dispatch` in `Objective-C`

Comment: This is a link only answer.  It would nice that you give a summary of how it works, so that the readers don't have to go all the files in the repo to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as in C++/C# with 2 single dispatches (aka "visitor" pattern, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++ ).

Or you can do it manually with some runtime type checking on the argument (see [isMemberOfClass](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418766-ismemberofclass)).

Comment: Do you have any simple example of Visitor pattern?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366079/visitor-pattern-in-objective-c